# Comma between two independent clauses subordinate to another clause

Tags: punctuation

I have learned that I need a comma between two independent clauses, e.g.,

*The tram service was disrupted, and the bus was too crowded.*

What if the clause pair is subordinate to another clause, e.g.,

*I went on foot because the tram service was disrupted, and the bus was too crowded.*

**Do I need the comma before *and*?**
I am inclined to avoid the comma so the last clause (i.e, *the bus was too crowded*) also appears as a reason for *going on foot*, not an independent clause.
What is the more accurate punctuation, with or without a comma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the comma; they are still separate clauses.

If you fear the impression that it's not the two reasons, perhaps you should recast the sentence.

> Because the tram service was disrupted, and the bus was too crowded, I went on foot.